# Set delay with javascript / ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, timeout, delay

**I want to make a `delay` when the `result` comes in the `note`.**

I have a `form` > `input` the user types his username in the `input` and I check with `AJAX`

if the `username` is available or not. If yes a `note` shows up near the `input` with the

`result`.

*Please no jQuery!*

Comment: I don't see what the question title has to do with the question body?

Comment: Why would you want the feedback to be delayed?

Comment: the script starts to run from the first word, so I don't want to show useless results... and looks better, and feels better :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) to display something after a short delay:

```
var delay = 1000;            // 1 second
var result = 'note here';    // the result from your AJAX response

setTimeout(function() { 
   document.getElementById('note').innerHTML = result; 
}, delay);
```